# Interacting(get itemcount, loop, click each item) with CUSTOM listview control?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

I am trying to interact with custom listview class, the class along with its instance is recognized by winapi but for sure it has problem interacting with it.

What i am trying to do is get item count then click on each(when required) but WinApi is unable to do anything about this.

`int nMaxItems = ListView_GetItemCount(hWndLV);`

I tried this but it fails, i **even hooked** on the thread of this listview, created fake window in the memory where listview is, sent that window a message which tells it to run a function which again does...

`int nMaxItems = ListView_GetItemCount(hWndLV);`

but even while doing this in the custom listview memory it produces nothing...

I am aware custom controls are not suitable for winapi but at least i was hoping to be able to get item count of it, then click... guess i was wrong

Like doing ocr wasnt enough of a problem that i already knew i will have to do.

So to recap i need to at least be able to get item count, loop, click on each...
If possible i would like to somehow get item text but i will be happy with just itemcount,clicking...

If you guys know some alternative/solution to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom listview class" - what's the classname? The ListView_ messages only work with SysListView32 controls (or controls that are subclasses of those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a *custom* control, and not the standard Windows control, it is under no obligation to honor the same set of messages that the standard controls respond to. If it doesn't recognize the same messages that the OS provides, then you'll just have to find out what mechanism, if any, it *does* provide for external code to interact with it.

Contact the vendor of that control and get the documentation. There's no standard interface.

If you ask a new question with more specifics, you might find that somebody already knows how to operate the control you're trying to deal with.